# Matlab reshaping Vector

Tags: matlab

I have a vector which is composed by over 200 30x30 matrixes.

When I try accessing an element of the vector, Matlab returns:

```
[30x30 double]
```

I am trying to reshape all elements of the vector into vectors themselves by calling:

```
arrayfun(@(n) reshape(n,1,[]), preMatrixes)
```

However, this simply returns the original vector.

Any thoughts on why this may be?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a cell-array of matrices. Try using `cellfun` instead of `arrayfun`.

Comment: Returns: Error using cellfun
Non-scalar in Uniform output, at index 1, output 1.
Set 'UniformOutput' to false.

Error in SetupVectors (line 7)
preMatrixesColumn = cellfun(@(n) reshape(n,1,[]), preMatrixes);

Comment: That means that you have to use `cellfun(@(n) reshape(n,1,[]), preMatrixes,'UniformOutput',false);` instead of what you used.